# Add HttpCookie to CookieStore

Tags: java

I need to add a few cookies to authorize on website. Cookies are added successfully, but they are missing when making a request:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {
    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieStore cookieJar = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name123", "value123");
        cookieJar.add(new URI("http://httpbin.org"), cookie);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://httpbin.org/cookies").openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader in;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}
```

But I only get an empty map of cookies in response

```
{  "cookies": {}}
```

Please, tell me what I should do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cookie.setPath( "/" );
cookie.setVersion( 0 );
```

Do the trick `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`